# Использование Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте. Копировать код не вижу смысла, поэтому сразу к проблеме.

У меня есть цикл while(true), в нём есть вызов метода messages.get из VKApi. Нужно сделать так, чтобы этот метод выполнялся с периодичностью раз в 5 секунд. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это лучше реализовать? Я думал использовать Thread.sleep(), но messages.get не успевает выполниться и цикл просто идёт дальше.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Думается, что Thread.sleep() не стоит использовать. Показывать код не вижу смысла тоже. Не благодарите

Comment: @АндроидАндроид спасибо большое